# Windows Phone Emulator 8.0 needs SLAT to run?

Tags: windows-8.1, virtualization, visual-studio-2013

After installing Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 with Update 2 I got this error message at the end of the installation, telling me that my computer does not support hardware virtualization, and that for this reason Windows Phone Emulator 8.0 can't run.

*Click for a larger image.*

[image: visual studio ultimate 2013 install]

I read a post on the [TechNet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/5bb5a6cd-4a5f-492f-aad1-7a5c3055acbd/this-computer-does-not-support-hardware-virtualization-which-means-windows-phone-emulator-80-cant?forum=w8itproinstall) forum that it requires SLAT (Second Level Address Translation). This is what I see when I run the Coreinfo utility from Sysinternals.

[image: coreinfo.exe -v]

I see SLAT listed there. But I'm not getting what the asterisk and the dash is indicating. Does this mean that the CPU does not support SLAT feature specifically? Because I'm pretty sure it has "hardware virtualization".

Comment: It says clearly in the screenshot. But for the record, it's an Intel Q9650. It's one of the most feature-packed models from the Core 2 Quad series. I know it's an obsolete CPU. I don't plan to decommission it just yet, and it has VT-x, so why won't it work?

Comment: btw, the latest VS2013 update is Update 3 and from Update 4 there is already a CTP.

Comment: Well the [Q9650](http://ark.intel.com/products/35428/Intel-Core2-Quad-Processor-Q9650-12M-Cache-3_00-GHz-1333-MHz-FSB) suports all of Intel's virtualization technology. Have you confirmed its enabled in the BIOS/UEFI?  Because your screenshot indicates that Hyper-V isn't even installed.  Did this ever work?

Comment: Yes, it's enabled in BIOS. Yes, this one supports VT-x and VT-d for directed I/O, but it does not support SLAT or EPT (extended page tables). But I'll manage without it.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Can I get Update 3 as a free download? I have the MSDNAA license, and only the image with Update 2 was offered.

Comment: yes, the Update 3 ISOs are free: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/search/DownloadResults.aspx?q=Visual%20Studio%202013%20Update%203

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows Phone Emulator uses Hyper-V and [Hyper-V in Windows 8 requires SLAT](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/bott/does-your-pc-have-what-it-takes-to-run-windows-8s-hyper-v/4254).

The `-` shows that you **DON't** have support for that feature, so you can't use the Windows Phone Emulator.

Comment: Thanks! So for the record; all Nehalem CPUs have SLAT support (EPT). I checked on Intel website, all Core i3, i8 and i7 CPUs [have it](http://ark.intel.com/Products/VirtualizationTechnology). So even though a given CPU supports VT-x technology, it doesn't necessarily support SLAT as well. One does not imply the other. This can be confusing sometimes. But I think I'll manage without SLAT anyway.